# How do I determine appropriate Date query syntax for a layer?

Tags: query, arcgis-rest-api

I'm writing a web mapping query tool to query Esri mapservice layers by date using the REST API.

It has [been said](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/4337-REST-API-Query-by-Date?p=14879&viewfull=1#post14879) that the syntax depends on what kind of database is behind the mapservice layer, as described in the [help doc](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm).

For oracle use this:

```
Datefield = date 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

For SQL Server use this:

```
Datefield = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
```

**How do I determine which database is being used by a particular mapservice layer so I can compose the query using the appropriate syntax?**

Comment: Although the Rest API theoretically abstracts away the data source, it would be nice to know if there some attribute or quirk that would indicate the data source for this kind of query. File this under the law of leaky abstractions http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html