# How to Query Layer using ArcGIS REST Services for Records with Date Closed Field less than 24 hours ago?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, time, arcgis-rest-api, date

I am current trying to do layer definitions on a map and so I am trying to filter some records via a time factor so i was writing in the `Where` field `DATE_CLOSED_ON > (CURRENT_TIME - 24) and DATE_CLOSED_ON is not NULL`

[image]

I believe that in order to query a date field there is a must to include the field is not null. As for the time factor I am trying to query records that are closed less than 24 hours ago but the query keep returning me all records with a non null `DATE_CLOSED_ON` field.

Comment: Which ArcGIS product and version is your screenshot and issue from?  It may be worth updating your tag(s) to that.

Comment: I am using arcgis 10.0, its not an issue but just what is the syntax for getting records less than 24 hours.

Comment: Is it ArcGIS Server?  Is it from one of the ArcGIS Viewers?  If so, which one?  I could investigate the ArcGIS Desktop equivalent but your screenshot does not look like it comes from there.

Comment: ArcGIS Server and I am using the REST services. `http://localhost/arcgis/rest/services/...` you get the idea..

Comment: See my related question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41216/how-do-i-determine-appropriate-date-query-syntax-for-a-layer

Comment: @KirkKuykendall what I am saying is that I know the different database will yield different syntax on the maplayerservice, but I just want to know is there anyone who knows the syntax. been looking high and low for the CURRENT_TIME - 24 hours syntax but have not yet found any.

Comment: What DBMS is behind the mapservice?  If Sql Server, did you try [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall thanks for replying, MSSQL is behind the mapservice and while CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the syntax for MSSQL, input that in the rest service query api will just inform me to check my parameters, I searched online and its CURRENT_TIME that works but its not returning me the incidents closed within 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax depends on the underlying database.  Assuming that it is sql server:

`DATE_CLOSED_ON >= DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())`